# Custom routing on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, rest, api, routes

I have some problem with `routing in  Laravel`. I have a route like this

```
$app->get('manufaktur/{secretkey}','Rest\LkppController@get_manufaktur');
```

it will generate URL like this :
https://baseurl/api/manufacture/my-secret-key.

Now, my problem is how to change that route so it would be like this
https://baseurl/api/manufacture?secretkey=my-secret-key.

Thanks before.

Comment: manufaktur `!=` manufacture

Comment: it's different language, so manufacture is manufaktur in my language.

Comment: Sure, but the route won't match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your is route should be :

```
 Route::get('/manufaktur','Rest\LkppController@get_manufaktur');
```

and in your `LkppController`

```
 public function get_manufaktur(Request $request){
     if ($request->has('secretkey')) {

        $secretKey = $request->query('secretkey');

        return response()->json(['status'=>'OK','secret_key'=>$secretKey]);

     }else{
          return response()->json(['status'=>'error','message'=>'Secret Key Required']);
      }
 }
```

Comment: how to validate the request on middleware? i've trying to print the output but no request displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `request()->query('secretkey')`
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#retrieving-input

Comment: i'm using Laravel 5.3, so i only use $request['secretkey'] on middleware. but this is can be done too.

Answer (score 1):

This type of URL `https://baseurl/api/manufacture?secretkey=my-secret-key` can be generated if you submit the form in `GET` type(GET/POST).

If you are creating API and you want URL like that you have to do it as hardcoded way.

Try this on your route.

```
$app->get('manufaktur?secretkey={secretkey}','Rest\LkppController@get_manufaktur');
```

Comment: i have tried this one, but i found that i don't have change anything.
and retreive the request with $request['secretkey'] on middleware.

Comment: and what about your URL?

Comment: i don't change the route, i only access https://baseurl/api/manufacture?secretkey=my-secret-key and i just validate $request['secretkey'] or $request->query('secretkey') on Middleware.

Comment: @elcicko I thought your priority was to change the URL as a question's title,  that's why I gave this answer :)

Comment: yeah, i thought my question title is little bit confusing :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$app->get('manufaktur','Rest\LkppController@get_manufaktur');
```

Then generate it with [url()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-url) helper